# Change the Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, url

I would like to change the URL for my Wordpress:

- From this: `www.example.com/wordpress`
- To this:     `www.example.com/game`

What do I need to do?

I tried renaming the Wordpress folder to `game` but this did not work. It caused a linkage problem with the bank-end database.

Comment: check out site URL in database, and try to update if folder name is exist in database.what error are you getting after rename folder name?

Comment: Unable to find the exact location please help.

Answer (score 0):

which server you are using.
if you are using apache or nginx you need to modify you vhost files accordingly to point to the right directory.
location of these file depend on you server's OS.
commonly it is in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ or /etc/apache2/conf.d/`

Comment: Using a free hosting and connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not open any file in this `www.example.com/wordpress` folder, Change `permission` this folder apply `755` permission, stop `apache` server or stop xampp. after rename your foder name and start apache server or `xammp`

Comment: Hey I am using a free domain and hosting of 000webhost and i am connecting to it using file zilla client i have uploaded the wordpress folder through file zilla and uploaded it on the domain.As my domain is example.com/wordpress --- > example.com/game(want to change to this)